# How to prevent lifetime issues between completion of background task and UI in Qt

Tags: c++, qt6

When using `QtConcurrent::run` to run code in the background from a UI the
`QFuture::then(QObject *context, Function &&function)` can be used to update the UI because you can pass the window object as context to make `function` execute on the GUI thread. This is very convenient however there is one problem. When the window is closed and it is deallocated before the background task completes the program will crash when the task completes because the `context` passed to `then` is no longer valid.

Is there an easy way to prevent this problem? I know a `QFutureWatcher` can be used but that object would need to be added to the window class and one would be needed for every asynchronous task the window can execute which is cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple option would be to use a [`QPointer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html) to track/monitor the `QWidget` of interest.  A copy of the `QPointer` can be captured by whatever lambdas or functors are used by `QtConcurrent::run` or `QFuture::then`.

```
/*
 * Set up the QWidget that we need to monitor.
 */
auto w = std::make_unique<QLabel>("Working...");
w->show();

/*
 * Create a QPointer that that we can use to check the validity of 'w'.
 */
auto qp = QPointer<QWidget>(w.get());

/*
 * We can now bind qp into any lambdas.
 */
auto f = QtConcurrent::run(
    []
    {

        /* Time consuming stuff goes here. */
    })
    .then(
        qApp,
        [qp]
        {
            if (qp) {

                /*
                 * qp reports that 'w' is still valid so do whatever we
                 * need to do with it.
                 */
                qp.data()->setText("Done");
            } else {

                /*
                 * 'w' is no longer valid.
                 */
            }
        });
```

[Note: the above is untested as I don't have `Qt6` on the box I'm working on right now.]